# How to change defualt parameter's name of overrided methods in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

When i write code with kotlin in intlli' or android studio , the defult parameter's name of overrided methods usually is p0 or p1 etc.

How can i change this parameter's name?

At least for more useable methods.

Comment: can't you just rename the variable in the header of the override method? like override fun onCreate(yourName: Bundle?)

Comment: Yes i can.but when i work with for example view holder that have more parameters its take my time

Comment: I think you just need to take your time and rename every variable you need. :)

Comment: Thanks for your useful help :)

Comment: Do you have the source code for the methods you override? If the source code is available, IDE should get the parameter names from it, otherwise it's not possible to get the original parameter names.